# ag-grid setRowData does not load any data

Tags: ag-grid

No data gets loaded in the grid. I am not where it is going wrong.
html:

```
        <div ng-controller="ScoreController">
            <div ag-grid="scoreCntl.gridOptions" class="ag-blue"
                style="height: 65%">                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:`$scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs : columnDefs

    };
         $http.get('url').success(function(data) {
            sampleData = data;

            $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
                $scope.gridOptions.api = gridApi;

                $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(scoreData);

            };

        });`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.gridOptions.onGridReady = function () {
    $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(scoreData);
}
```

Comment: Put your setRowData inside onGridReady function becoz some time grid is not initialised so your api would be undefined so i tihink dats the issue..